# Open-Xchange Installation "The maximum number of contexts in every database cluster has been reached"

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, database, open-xchange

I'm currently trying to configure my Ubuntu Server with Open-Xchange for personal use.
I've got Open-Xchange up and running (all the databases and users have been created, the site is reachable via HTTPS, etc).

Currently, I'm having some trouble creating the required context and sadly I can't find any information about this.

Here is the command I'm calling:
`createcontext -A oxadminmaster -P '</snip>' -c 1 -u oxadmin -d "Context Administrator" -g Admin -s User -p '</snip>' -L defaultcontext -e oxadmin@myhost -q 1024 --access-combination-name=groupware_standard`

I'm getting the following error:

```
context 1 could not be created:
Server response:
 The maximum number of contexts in every database cluster has been reached. Use register-, create- or change database to resolve the problem.
        at com.openexchange.admin.storage.mysqlStorage.OXUtilMySQLStorage.getNextDBHandleByWeight(OXUtilMySQLStorage.java:3940)
        at com.openexchange.admin.plugin.hosting.storage.mysqlStorage.OXContextMySQLStorage.create(OXContextMySQLStorage.java:1601)
        at com.openexchange.admin.plugin.hosting.rmi.impl.OXContext.createmaincall(OXContext.java:1347)
        at com.openexchange.admin.rmi.impl.OXContextCommonImpl.createcommon(OXContextCommonImpl.java:174)
        at com.openexchange.admin.plugin.hosting.rmi.impl.OXContext.create(OXContext.java:468)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:303)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:279)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:161)
        at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227)
        at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.create(Unknown Source)
        at com.openexchange.admin.console.context.Create.maincall(Create.java:143)
        at com.openexchange.admin.console.context.CreateCore.commonfunctions(CreateCore.java:147)
        at com.openexchange.admin.console.context.Create.<init>(Create.java:80)
        at com.openexchange.admin.console.context.Create.main(Create.java:84)
```

Seeming as initconfigdb and registerdatabase didn't create any databases, I went ahead and created an empty one:

```
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| configdb           |
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| oxglobal           |
```

Here is the output from the db_pool table:

```
+------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+------+---------+----------+
| db_pool_id | url                         | driver                | login        | password       | hardlimit | max  | initial | name     |
+------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+------+---------+----------+
|          3 | jdbc:mysql://mail.hyhost    | com.mysql.jdbc.Driver | openexchange |                |         1 |  100 |       0 | oxglobal |
+------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+------+---------+----------+
```

Am I missing something here? I've tried dropping the configdb database and calling all the steps from their setup tutorial, but I've reached the same point again.

Any help on the matter is appreciated.

Comment: Is some SQL statement involved?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure. I've posted the command above, but I don't know what it does in the background. The other commands worked just fine, so I'm assuming that the SQL connection isn't an issue.